# Can't enqueue Google Maps JS API to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm quite new to WordPress and I'm following a Udemy course on theme development and one part involves using the Google Maps API. When I register/enqueue the script, it doesn't appear in the HTML source code when viewing the page. There are also no errors in the developer console either.

This is a snippet from my `functions.php`:

```
    wp_register_script('googlemaps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&key=AIzaSyCCyUD3v8kBVRphqG1RYjYcSKBcyC-prKw&callback=initMap', array(''), '', true);
    wp_register_script('fluidboxjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.fluidbox.min.js', array('jquery'), '2.0.5', true);
    wp_register_script('script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('googlemaps');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('fluidboxjs');
    wp_enqueue_script('script');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lapizzeria_styles');
```

And this is the HTML that is output below the footer (I believe I should be seeing a link to the Google API here):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/udemy/lapizzeria/wp-content/themes/lapizzeria/js/jquery.fluidbox.min.js?ver=2.0.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/udemy/lapizzeria/wp-content/themes/lapizzeria/js/scripts.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/udemy/lapizzeria/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7.4'></script>
```

Interestingly this line does appears in the head when I enqueue `googlemaps`:

```
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//maps.googleapis.com' />
```

As a bit of background on the issue:

The first step in the exercise was to place [Google's sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) (script & styles) directly into `front-page.php` and the map displayed fine.

The second step was moving that code out from the `front-page.php` and placing it in `functions.php`, `scripts.js`, and `style.css`.

Moving the styles to `style.css` works fine. Moving the `initMap()` function to `scripts.js` works fine. But when attempting to enqueue/register the Google Maps API in `functions.php` it doesn't seem to be adding the `<script>` for the Maps API under the footer as it does for other enqueued items.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference but I'm working locally and running MAMP. I've tried clearing my browser cache and using a different browser. I've tried changing the order in which it is enqueued.

**EDIT:**
One thing I have noticed, is that if I put a dependency in for `googlemaps` it DOES print the `<script>` tag I'm expecting but brings up this error in the console: `initMap is not a function`. My understanding is that Google Maps API shouldn't require jQuery to work so I'm not sure if this bit of extra info is relevant.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCCyUD3v8kBVRphqG1RYjYcSKBcyC-prKw&#038;callback=initMap&#038;ver=4.7.4'></script>
```

Maybe something fishy going on with the `#038;` appearing in the line above?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would protect your googleMapAPI key now that they are charging for use of using it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect the issue is due to the dependency that has been set for `googlemaps`. Instead of passing in an empty array to specify no dependencies for the script, the array contains a blank string. The dependency can't be satisfied so the script isn't loaded.

Simply replace `array('')` with `array()`.

```
wp_register_script('googlemaps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&key=AIzaSyCCyUD3v8kBVRphqG1RYjYcSKBcyC-prKw&callback=initMap', array(), '', true);
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that.